# Publish Errors on any project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, publish

tried to publish a nopcommerce 3.9 app on my server and i got this error

> publish has encountered an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object 
>   A diagnostic log has been written to following location

Log File:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.InitializeProvider(IVsHierarchy hierarchy)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.DefaultPublishTabProvider.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Provider.ManagedPublishProvider.d__1.MoveNext()

and i haven't installed SQL Server yet on my pc,haven't installed NopCommerce on my pc either and never made any changes to the source code

Edit:it's not  duplicate of another question because in that case i would have gotten a run time error this happens when i want to publish it and the program runs just fine and my problem is in publish scenario

Comment: You cannot say *my case is different* `NullReferenceException` is because of very straight forward..somewhere you're playing with null..  **why it's not working is also off topic here**..even if you're not consider as duplicate question.

Comment: Moreover, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Div This is a null reference exception, but judging by the stack trace, this is not user code, it's in the `Microsoft` package. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Rob: Alright!, retracted flag as duplicate.

Comment: Though OP should add more information, is it only issue with nopCommerce? or with default template publishing also not working..

Comment: @Div publishing isn't working at all(i can't publish anything)sry for delay

Comment: @user9306199: Could you please try with vs2015, there is something wrong with vs2017.. or you can try to repair vs2017

Comment: @user9306199: There are multiple thread regarding publishing error with VS, you can use CLI to publish the application(alternate solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS 2017 V15.5.5 has a bug in publishing try updating your VS

Answer (score 3):

You are referencing a path to publish your code in the middle of nowhere. Just check the path and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Repair your visual studio and run as administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Change the target location in publish profile,
this error occurs when same folder used for more than one project.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have "could not find" files in your project

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer and there are some others, expose the Pros of yours. In this case, you are asking to check something, explain why it is a solution.